# Smooth out signal from remote sensor

Tags: mosfet, noise, mixed-signal

I have a remote (wired) device with a MOSFET and some analog sensor with some inherent noise I want to smooth out.

I decided to go with a simple RC filter but upon inspection I realized that my signal is way worse than without the filter as I get extra noise at the switching frequency of the MOSFET.

After some investigation and basic modeling this is my best theory:

[image]

I simulate noise on the ground plane. Because the device is remote and I use thin gauge wire, I add a series resistor between the ground of the sensor and the ground of where I do the measurement.

Because the ADC has a high input impedance there is no voltage drop on the wire. When the device ground "moves" the capacitor charges through the 33k resistor but when the transient is over it has nowhere to discharge and I continue reading a disturbed value for a while.

I'm a beginner so I'm not sure if this is a common problem and what are classic solution.

1. Is there a way to reduce the switching noise on the device? I added 10 uF of capacitors and it doesn't seem to help. I even tried having the MOSFET with no load and the noise is still there so it seems that there is just no way of getting rid of it.
2. I guess I could do the filtering just before the measurement and not on device side but I'd rather avoid it since I want to be able to plug multiple sensors to the same connector and they don't all need the same amount of filtering.
3. Is there anything else I could do? Maybe an RL filter instead of RC?
4. Should I try transmitting my signal with current instead of voltage?

Edit:

- Add a schematic that includes the mosfet (and removes the modeled noise source)
  [image]

Adding a trace of the noise on ground (measurement referenced on the main board where the ADC is)
[image]

The big spikes are at both edges of my switching signal (50% duty, 10KHz). I haven't started investigating the smaller ones but they seem to not be disturbing the final signal so I didn't bother.

Comment: That picture isn't clear to me. Where is your sensor and where do you measure? Maybe place the sensor part on the left and the place of measurement on the right with with long connections in between.

One way to transmit sensitive signal over longer distances is to use differential signaling.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: Regarding 4, the main reason to use current instead of voltage signal is to take away cable resistance from the equation. If the noise is external and is inducing voltage in your cable, an ideal current source as signal generator would not be affected by it. In real life, your noise source is probably elsewhere. Can you show a schematic with your sensor+MOSFET and an oscilloscope capture of said noise?

Comment: @winny Just added those to the post. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What's the purpose of the MOSFET? You're injecting noise from it from +5 V to GND over your 5.6 ohm (cable?) resistance. Try adding a capacitor from +5 V to GND on your remote device.

Comment: The 5.6Ohm was to model the cable yes. In my diagram (and the measurements) the 5V isn't actually connected. Originally there was an inductive load that I actually removed and the problem is still there. As mentioned in my post I tried adding a 10u between 5V and GND on the device already and saw no appreciable change.

Comment: So between which points is the probe of your oscilloscope connected in the measurement shown above (probe tip and ground lead)? How are both sides (sensor and ADC) powered? Could you show us a schematic of your setup, not just the model?

Comment: @11011100 the ground lead of the oscilloscope is connected to the ground of the ADC. Probe tip is on the negative side of the 470p capacitor. Power is USB and transmitted to the sensor via the same long wire.. The second schematic is the real setup, sensor is powered by the 5V wire and it's a photo transistor. Should I make another one? I'm afraid it will make the post too long.